# Spring Data JPA Determine Overlapping date range

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data Jpa

I have the below objects

```
public class VehicleDetail {
    private long vehicleDetailId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleDetail")
    private List<NonAvailabilityStatus> nonAvailabilityStatus = new ArrayList<NonAvailabilityStatus>();
}

public class NonAvailabilityStatus{

    private long nonAvailabilityStatusId;

    @Column(name="START_DT_TM")
    private Date nonAvailabiltyStartDateTime;

    @Column(name="END_DT_TM")
    private Date nonAvailabiltyEndDateTime;
}
```

I want to check if the current date and current date+1 overlaps between `nonAvailabiltyStartDateTime` and `nonAvailabiltyEndDateTime` using method name query. I tried `findByNonAvailabilityStatusNonAvailabiltyStartDateTimeIsBeforeAndNonAvailabilityStatusNonAvailabiltyEndDateTimeAfter(Date startDate, Date endDate)`, and it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried using [`@Query`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) annotations or a [custom repository](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories) where you explicitly let the code know what to do?

Comment: For instance, in my case I wanted to see if there is dates overlapping with the `from` and `to` values of my `foo` item, so I added this method in my `FooRepository`:
`@Query(value = "{'dateFrom': {$lt: ?1}, 'dateTo': {$gt: ?0}}") Option<Foo> findOverlap(long from, long to);`